# How to solve the unmet dependencies issue when to install wine32?

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

Show my wine's version info:

```
wine --version
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
wine-1.8.7 (Debian 1.8.7-2)
```

Install wine32 according to the info.

```
sudo apt-get install -y wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 1.8.7-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Show more unmet dependencies when to install libwine:i386:

```
sudo apt install -y libwine:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwine:i386 : Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                         libglu1:i386
                Recommends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                            libgl1:i386
                Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Try to install with `f` argument.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Does all dependencies install?

```
wine --version
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
wine-1.8.7 (Debian 1.8.7-2)
```